# How to change Bluetooth MAC address on RockPi S?

Tags: linux, bluetooth

I'm trying to set up the MAC address of my Bluetooth device for an application, but every time I restart it, it changes the MAC address and creates a new one. I would like to know if there is any way to make it static and set my preferred MAC address.

On the radxa website: https://wiki.radxa.com/RockpiS/Debian#BT, they have a tutorial on how to change the Bluetooth MAC address using terminal commands, but it doesn't work as shown in the image below.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oD6P4.png)

I tried using hciconfig, but as seen in the image, it didn't work. I also attempted to use the bdaddr command as indicated in other tutorials, but I always receive the message "command not found," even after installing the bluez-utils utilities using "apt-get install bluez-utils."
I tried using the command "hcitool cmd 'hcitool cmd 0x04 0x009'," but after a while, I started receiving the following result: "Device open failed: No such device"

Comment: Yes, I rebooted. In the image, I rebooted right after I issued the command for the new MAC address as instructed on the Radxa website. But I reboot and check again, and it shows a MAC address different from the first one and different from the one I provided.